# Use NSDictionary to calculate with words in UITextField

Tags: uitextfield, nsdictionary

In short, my question is, if the user types a word for example "mvg" I want the textfield to register the word as a number, so I can calculate with it, how do I do that?

I made a dictionary like this:

```
NSDictionary * dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
[NSNumber numberWithInt: 20], @"mvg",
[NSNumber numberWithInt: 15], @"vg",
[NSNumber numberWithInt: 10], @"g", nil];
```

Now I need the dictionary to register the users typing and translate the words into the numbers. Anyone know how I should do?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to do? Given what you've done, you can recall any numerical value by simply asking the dictionary for the object associated with the given string. Dictionaries are merely containers so they don't register or translate anything. They simply hold keys and the values associated with those keys. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @user1118321
I have several textfields and the principle of my app is to calculate them together. The user can write two different things, either numbers or  those three words. I haven't got problems with the actual calculations, it's calculating with the words.

Comment: So what are you asking for then? Are you asking how to get the words out of the text fields and into the dictionary?

Comment: I want the user to type one of those words in a textfield and some numbers in other textfields, and when they press a button named "calculate" get an answer in numbers. Right know the program take the word as the value 0, when I instead  want to have a certain value of those words :) hope you understand, because I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a view controller and the views. You already have the text fields and buttons (the views). Now you need to make the button perform an action when pressed. If you've set the UI up in Interface Builder, you should be able to simply connect the "Touch Up Inside" outlet of the button to your action in the controller. If you're doing it programmatically, then you need to set the action and target for the button to the appropriate method on the appropriate object (usually the view controller). That method will then read the values from the other text fields (which should be outlets in the object, which should be the view controller) and do your calculations.